# JQuery autocomplete with xml source not working

Tags: jquery

I have two types of input textboxes which I need to complete with two different data sources. My problem is that one of them works fine but the second does not. Here is my code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var cities = [];
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "AIRPORTS.xml", 
             dataType: "xml",
             success: parseXml,
             complete: setupAC,
             failure: function (data) {
                 alert("XML File could not be found");
             }
         });

         function parseXml(xml) {
             //find every query value
             $(xml).find("AIRPORT").each(function () {
                     cities.push($(this).find("CITY").text() + ", " + $(this).find("COUNTRY").text());
                 }
             });
         }

         function setupAC() {
             $("input#cheapFlightList_cityLabel_0").autocomplete({
                 source: cities,
                 minLength: 1,
                 select: function (event, ui) {
                     $("input#cheapFlightList_cityLabel_0").val(ui.item.value);
                     $('#cheapFlightList_cityLabel_0').blur();
                 }
             });
         }



         var airlines = [];
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "AIRLINES.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: parseXmlAirlines,
             complete: setupACAirlines,
             failure: function (data) {
                 alert("XML File could not be found");
             }
         });

         function parseXmlAirlines(xml) {
             //find every query value
             $(xml).find("AIRLINE").each(function () {
                 airlines.push($(this).find("NAME").text());
             });
         }

         function setupACAirlines() {
             $("input#cheapFlightList_cityID_0").autocomplete({
                 source: airlines,
                 minLength: 1,
                 select: function (event, ui) {
                     $("input#cheapFlightList_cityID_0").val(ui.item.value);
                     $('#cheapFlightList_cityID_0').blur();
                 }
             });
         }
     });
```

The one with source `cities` works fine but the one with source `airlines` does not. Although airlines array does fill up with airline names.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

AIRPORTS.xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AIRPORTCODES>
<AIRPORT>
    <NAME>Aachen-Merzbruck</NAME>
    <CITY>Aachen</CITY>
    <COUNTRY>Germany</COUNTRY>
    <ISO>DE</ISO>
    <WAC>623</WAC>
    <IATA>AAH</IATA>
</AIRPORT>
</AIRPORTCODES>
```

AIRLINES.xml sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AIRLINES>
<AIRLINE>
    <NAME>ABSA Cargo Airline</NAME>
</AIRLINE>
</AIRLINES>
```

I have validated xml with online validator and it is fine.

**EDIT 2**

The generated markup for my working input is:

```
<input name="cheapFlightList$ctrl0$cityLabel" type="text" value="Lahore" id="cheapFlightList_cityLabel_0" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

while the generated markup for non working textbox is:

```
<input name="cheapFlightList$ctrl0$CityID" type="text" value="Aegean Airlines" id="cheapFlightList_CityID_0">
```

Comment: please provide sample of XML

Comment: it's not necessary.  it's just a callback definition. @MackieeE

Comment: I've debugged code and it works OK. So question. how much Airlines you expect to get here. as For me only 1 row.

Comment: around 230. Can you post the code you wrote?

Comment: nothing specific, actually. I just copied source of your function 

seee http://plnkr.co/edit/wP6etWuyEQJvfJujhiFr?p=preview

Comment: ahhh solved! one of the most stupid mistakes! it was cheapFlightList_CityID_0 instead of cheapFlightList_cityID_0. I looked over and over but couldn't see. So sorry I wasted your time. Thanks